# Is there a way to load async data on InitState method?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm a looking for a way to load async data on InitState method, I need some data before build method runs. I'm using a GoogleAuth code, and I need to execute build method 'till a Stream runs.

My initState method is:

```
 @override
  void initState () {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account)     {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }
```

I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: `StreamBuilder` is the correct solution

Comment: This code is absolutely fine as is?

Comment: Since `initState()` only gets called once, is there any point in using `setState()` inside it?

Comment: Also consider FutyureBuilder as it blocks *once* on waiting for an async method; where as stream builder pattern is a continuios sequence of unsolicted events.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can create an `async` method and call it inside your `initState`

```dart
@override
void initState () {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    _asyncMethod();
  });
        
}

_asyncMethod() async {
  _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account)     {
    setState(() {
      _currentUser = account;
    });
  });
  _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't change anything, unless his call is sync and instant. But then there's no async problem

Comment: Ini this case `build` executed BEFORE `_asyncMethod` completed!

Comment: @diegoveloper what is the purpose of using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` instead of @Nae answer?

Comment: It is wrong to call setState() when you are initing the state, this causes refresh on page after page is loaded because you're calling an async method in initState. The soulution is only FutureBuilder().

Comment: no, it's fine, because I'm using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback

Comment: Is there any difference with `SchedulerBinding`?

Comment: @BISTech the reason to use the  `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is because the async method calls `setState()` without the callback the state may be attempted to be changed before the `initState()` method completes which is forbidden.

Comment: @AutoM8R No it's not right? Imagine I have a Future function it just returns a value without await. Ex: 
`Future<model> _asyncMethod() async { return model; };`
If I write two print statements inside `addPostFrameCallback` and `_asyncMethod().then` method, first print addPostFrameCallback's print and then asynMethod print.

Comment: Full Code: 
```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print('called : addPostFrameCallback');
    });
    db.asyncFuntion().then((value){
      print('called : asyncFuntion');
    });
```

Comment: @BISTech essentially `initState()` completes, build completes, frame drawn, callback occurs then you can await for an async method to complete and use `setState()` safely. What you're saying does not negate what I am saying. The order of execution which matters is the fact the build has completed, not the order of the async methods themselves. No async method with an embedded `setState()` should run without knowing the build has completed, that's the point of this callback.

Answer (score 113):

As of now using `.then` notation seems to work:

```
  // ...
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    myAsyncFunction
    // as suggested in the comment
    // .whenComplete() {
    // or
      .then((result) {
    print("result: $result");
    setState(() {});
    });
  }
  //...
```

Comment: if your async function not return anything, use `whenComplete` instead.

Comment: @Aravin Personally I prefer streams as much as possible. But this 'works' for demonstrative purposes. I'd very much doubt that this would be the _right_ way.

Comment: I get "Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()".

Comment: @Eradicatore It sounds like the widget is disposed of before your async function finishes.

Comment: Yea, my fault.  I figured it out.  So I had some code in place to avoid calling my cloud init functions twice in a row too fast, but didn't realize that flutter was starting up my stateful widget twice rapidly at every boot.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145378/why-is-initstate-called-twice).  I was trying to avoid waste calls to my cloud functions. So my widget tree really was disposed for the first call to my stateful widget.

Comment: @Nae What's the actual difference between using streams vs using setState?

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar Streams are the de facto way to build widgets as they come, the above answer is just a hacky way to load asynchronously, but managing the lifetime of the widget etc. is much harder.

Comment: Thank's a lot, work's well with progress indicator     super.initState();
    UpDateList()  //.whenComplete(){
        .then((result) {
      //print("result: $result");
      setState(() {isLoading=result;});
    });

Answer (score 68):

**Method 1 :** You can use **StreamBuilder** to do this. This will run the **builder** method whenever the data in **stream** changes.

Below is a code snippet from one of my sample projects:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Content>> _getContentsList(BuildContext context) {
    final BlocProvider blocProvider = BlocProvider.of(context);
    int page = 1;
    return StreamBuilder<List<Content>>(
        stream: blocProvider.contentBloc.contents,
        initialData: [],
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
            return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index < snapshot.data.length) {
                return ContentBox(content: snapshot.data.elementAt(index));
              } else if (index / 5 == page) {
                page++;
                blocProvider.contentBloc.index.add(index);
              }
            });
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

In the above code **StreamBuilder** listens for any change in contents, initially its an empty array and shows the **CircularProgressIndicator**. Once I make API call the data fetched is added to contents array, which will run the **builder** method.

When the user scrolls down, more content is fetched and added to contents array which will again run **builder** method.

In your case only initial loading will be required. But this provides you an option to display something else on the screen till the data is fetched.

Hope this is helpful.

**EDIT:**

In your case I am guessing it will look something like shown below:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Content>>(
        stream: account, // stream data to listen for change
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(account != null) {
                return _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
            } else {
                // show loader or animation
            }
        });
```

**Method 2:** Another method would be to create an `async` method and call it from you `initState()` method like shown below:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncMethod();
  }

  void asyncMethod() async {
    await asyncCall1();
    await asyncCall2();
    // ....
  }
```

Comment: Maybe adapt your snippet to his stream

Comment: @RémiRousselet edited the answer to add info like you asked. Please check if its correct.

Comment: Method 2 was simple and easy, and worked for me. Thanks

Comment: For Method 2, is there a way to then trigger setState() at the end of the await calls?  I try this and I see that "mounted" is now false so setState() produces an error. @RémiRousselet

Answer (score 32):

Create anonymous function inside `initState` like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  // Create anonymous function:
  () async {
    await _performYourTask();
    setState(() {
     // Update your UI with the desired changes. 
    });
  } ();
}
```

Comment: Please have some courage to mention the reason behind downvoting.

Comment: How's this different than calling `_performYourTask();` directly? How does wrapping the async function with another async function that is not awaited help?

Comment: In the above anonymous function you can call `setState` after `_performYourTask` is done (which you surely can't do in the `initState` directly)

Comment: So the extra wrap is reserved for queueing `setState` call after the wanted async method is _finished_. I'd then suggest adding that line after the `await`. Because right now it doesn't seem to be doing anything different.

Answer (score 8):

Previous Answer!!

You can set a Boolean value like loaded and set it to true in your listen function and make your build function return your data when loaded is set to true otherwise just throw a CircularProgressIndicator

Edited --
I would not suggest calling setState in a method you call in initState. If the widget is not mounted while the setState is called (as the async operation completes) an error will be reported. I suggest you use a package [after_layout](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout)

Take a look at this answer for better understanding setState in initState : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373017/9206337

This post will give you an idea to know when the app finishes the build method. So that you can wait for your async method to setState after widget is mounted : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/9206337

Answer (score 8):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncInitState(); // async is not allowed on initState() directly
  }

  void asyncInitState() async {
    await yourAsyncCalls();
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: No, doesnt work. put a print in initState and build and the code inside asyncInitState executes after build

Comment: asyncInitState() executes only when widget is build. Try to use yourAsyncCalls().then((value)=>'Your code here') inside in initState.

Comment: this worked, thank you! It's very likely other solutions also work but would be curious to know why the more complicated ones like using FutureBuilder would be preferred to this

Comment: welcome. For me, the simpler, the better.

Answer (score 8):

You can create an **async** method and call it inside your **initState**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    asyncMethod(); ///initiate your method here
  }

Future<void> asyncMethod async{
 
 await ///write your method body here
}
```

Comment: But you can't `await` the `asyncMethod()`

Comment: @AlaaM. Why not? Here is the code snippet that I have used. i am calling an API with await.

  initState() {
    getAPIData();
    super.initState();
  }

  getAPIData() async {
    await AuthService().checkConnectivity();
  }

Comment: This code doesn't wait for `getAPIData()`. I.e. `build()` could be run before `getAPIData()` finishes. Put `print` statements and check it.

Answer (score 6):

Per documentation at https://pub.dev/packages/provider

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(() =>
    context.read<MyNotifier>(context).fetchSomething(someValue);
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
@override
void initState() {
 //you are not allowed to add async modifier to initState
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() async {
  //your async 'await' codes goes here
 });
 super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`initState()` and `build` cannot be async; but in these, you can call a function that is async without waiting for that function.

Answer (score 3):

Sample code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    asyncOperation().then((val) {
      setState(() {});
      print("success");
    }).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
      print("outer: $error");
    });

//or

    asyncOperation().whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {});
      print("success");
    }).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
      print("outer: $error");
    });
  }

  Future<void> asyncOperation() async {
    await ... ;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As loading or waiting for initial state is a (generally) aone off event FutureBuilder would seem to be a good option as it blocks once on an async method; where the async method could be the loading of json config, login etc. There is an post on it [here] in stack.([Flutter StreamBuilder vs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844519/flutter-streambuilder-vs-futurebuilder))

Answer (score 1):

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _userStorage.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user.isAuthenticated) {
          Timer.run(() {
            redirectTo();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

 void redirectTo() {
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ShopOrders()));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using a `FutureBuilder`. It takes care of executing the async function and building the widget according to the result!
[Here's a link to a short intro video and the documentation.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Code Example:

```
  Future<void> initControllers() async {
    for (var filePath in widget.videoFilePaths) {
      var val = VideoPlayerController.file(File(filePath));
      await val.initialize();
      controllers.add(val);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FutureBuilder(
          future: initControllers(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return YourWidget();
            } else {
              return const ProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all suggestions, none would keep my build from starting after the async method that I need in initState() finish, except one: the trick of having a a bool variable in the State class (let's call it _isDataLoaded) that is initialized to false upon definition, set to true inside a setState() that is invoked when the async function finishes inside initState(). In the build, condition a CircleProcessIndicator() or your Widget depending on the value of this variable.

I know it's dirty because it could break the build, but honestly nothing else that would make more sense -such as running super.initState() upon completion of the async function- has worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I came here because I needed to fetch some files from FTP on program start. My project is a flutter desktop application. The main thread download the last file added to the FTP server, decrypts it and displays the encrypted content, this method is called from initState(). I wanted to have all the other files downloaded in background after the GUI shows up.

None of the above mentioned methods worked. Constructing an Isolate is relatively complex.

The easy way was to use the "compute" method:

1. move the method downloading all files from the FTP out of the class.
2. make it an int function with an int parameter (I do not use the int parameter or the result)
3. call it from the initState() method

In that way, the GUI shows and the program downloads the files in background.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _retrieveFileList(); // this gets the first file and displays it
    compute(_backgroundDownloader, 0); // this gets all the other files so that they are available in the local directory
  }

int _backgroundDownloader(int value) {
  var i = 0;
  new Directory('data').createSync();
  FTPClient ftpClient = FTPClient('www.guckguck.de',
      user: 'maxmusterman', pass: 'maxmusterpasswort');
  try {
    ftpClient.connect();
    var directoryContent = ftpClient.listDirectoryContent();
    // .. here, fileNames list is reconstructed from the directoryContent

    for (i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
      var dirName = "";
      if (Platform.isLinux)
        dirName = 'data/';
      else
        dirName = r'data\';
      var filePath = dirName + fileNames[i];
      var myDataFile = new File(filePath);
      if (!myDataFile.existsSync())
        ftpClient.downloadFile(fileNames[i], File(filePath));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw (err);
  } finally {
    ftpClient.disconnect();
  }
  return i;
```

Answer (score -2):

**I have used timer in initState**

```
Timer timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) async {
      await this.getUserVerificationInfo();
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
}

getUserVerificationInfo() async {
   await someAsyncFunc();
   timer.cancle();
}
```