# onGenerateRoute called multiple times

Tags: flutter, routes

In my main method I have

```
onGenerateRoute: (route) {
        print(route);
        return Router.generateRoute(route);
      }
```

If I enter URL with `https://myurl.com/#/foo/bar` I can see printing is called multiple times.

```
/
```

```
/foo
```

```
/foo/bar
```

I have an issue because I want to enter `bar` path, but it gets entered `foo` instead.

Any ideas how should I proceed?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Any solution here

Comment: This question has the same root cause as this question: [Why is initState() called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145378/why-is-initstate-called-twice/69927057#69927057). I provided an [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69927057/1903781) that is applicable to both

Answer (score 11):

It gets worse. Set the initalRoute to `/home/1/2/3/4/5` and the onGenerateRoute will be called 7 times.

You can make it less terrible with:

```
MaterialApp app;

app = MaterialApp(
    onGenerateInitialRoutes: (initialRoute)=>[app.onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings(name:initialRoute))],
    initialRoute: initial,
    onGenerateRoute: app.onGenerateRoute);
```

This avoid you're Route's initState being called multiple times and one onGenerateRoute per '/' in the path. However, is still calls onGenerateRoute twice if you supply a path in the browser bar.

I've submitted a bug report: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71786

Comment: How do you do this with null safety? I'm getting issues on the app.onGenerateRoute line