# Can I use await without async function?

Tags: flutter, async-await

I want to  declare a variable that receives the result of asynchronous function.

```
var eff_histo= await _eff_histo(selectedline);
```

The await expression can only be used in an asynchronous function

Comment: It highly depends upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is not possible as of now, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You still are misunderstanding `async`. The `async` keyword does *not* mean "run on another thread".

To push some code onto another thread, you need to do it explicitly, e.g., `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId));
```

I have an [`async`/`await` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a ***philosophy*** that a synchronous method should not wait because other important tasks may be affected, time taking async tasks however can take their time thus await makes sense there. Look into this for more information https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22269#issuecomment-108458526

Answer (score -1):

you can't used await outside async function ,, try to build your varable localy and declare your varable inside initState

```
var eff_histo;
@override
void initState() async {
super.initState()
eff_histo= await _eff_histo(selectedline);

}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cant change the `initState()` method. By changing i refer to adding the `async` tag. A new method should be created and then use the async on that method, then call the new method in the initState()  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901311/4712391

Comment: I can't use async in initState fun !