# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("color")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve color from firestore. But everytime I do I get this below error:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("color")
```

Here is my code:

```
 bool cardColor = false;
  String _userId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfColorOrNot();
  }

  checkIfColorOrNot() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      _userId = user.uid;
    });
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('rackBookItems')
        .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
        .collection('user')
        .document(_userId)
        .get();
    this.setState(() {
      cardColor = ds.exists; // If the above if exists then cardColor  is turned true else it stays flase
    });
  }

  

_cardColorApply(child) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      _userId = user.uid;
    });
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: cardColor 
          ? Firestore.instance
              .collection('rackBookItems')
              .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
              .collection('user')
              .document(_userId)
              .snapshots() // this should be shows only when cardColor is true
          : Firestore.instance
              .collection('rackBookItems')
              .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
              .snapshots(), // this should be shows only when cardColor is false
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        
       //Check to make sure snapshot.hasData has data or not 
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        int colorValue = int.parse(snapshot.data['color']);
        return Card(
          color: Color(colorValue),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }



@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: widget.onTap,
          child: _cardColorApply(_listItems()),
        );
      }
```

I am using statefull widget for this. The the info under document(_userId) is added last as so this will be initially null and so when its null want to access document(widget.rackBookItems.id) for color info.
Let me know if need any more information to get solution for this.

when cardColor = false my database will be like this so it can access color from
document(widget.rackBookItems.id)

[image]

after doing some task the database changes to this below one so cardColor changed to true and also color can be accessed from document(_userId)

[image]
ERROR:

[image]

Comment: its saying that snapshot.data is null. Can you show us how your database looks like?

Comment: yes sure, I have added screenshot of database that you asked for.

Comment: I meant your database structure. Can you try printing out snapshot.data to check if its null or not?

Comment: when I give print(snapshot.data); it shows this : 
I/flutter (31146): Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'

Comment: try this `!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty`

Comment: I did try this earlier and now again I tried, it gives me the same error : The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("color")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_userId` is returning null, that's why you are not getting any data. You need to create the following methods:

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getUserDocument() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await getCurrentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('rackBookItems')
        .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
        .collection('user')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }


  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getRackDocument() async* {
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('rackBookItems')
        .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
        .snapshots();
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  }
```

Then inside the `checkIfColorOrNot()` add the retrieval of the document inside the callback, to make sure that it gets execute after retrieving the `userId`:

```
  checkIfColorOrNot() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      _userId = user.uid;
      DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('rackBookItems')
          .document(widget.rackBookItems.id)
          .collection('user')
          .document(_userId)
          .get();
      this.setState(() {
        cardColor = ds.exists; // If the above if exists then cardColor  is turned true else it stays flase
      });
    });
  }
```

In the `StreamBuilder` do the following:

```
_cardColorApply(child) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: cardColor ? getUserDocument() : getRackDocument(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
       else if(snapshot.hasData){
        int colorValue = int.parse(snapshot.data['color']);
        return Card(
          color: Color(colorValue),
          child: child,
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for the your help. But there is small issue, I no longer get the error but the app does not do what I wanted it to. cardColor when false it should show the color that's in getRackDocument()  and when cardColor is true it should show the color that's in  getUserDocument(), currently cardColor even if its true it shows the color that's in getRackDocument(). Could you help me out on this part.

Comment: inside the method `_cardColorApply(child) {` can you do `print(cardColor)`

Comment: cardColor is still showing false even when its generated in firestore. One more thing user.uid generated in this cod does not match the user ID generated in the firebase. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In your code you are doing `document(_userId)` which means you are assigning the currently logged in user id to the document.. Therefore in the database you should have the user id as a document id... If you dont have that then you need to change your database

Comment: That's Correct. I have my user Id as my document ID which is stored in firestore. But when I print(_userId) this does not give out that current user Id. Still figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: did you follow the code i gave you? `user.uid` should give u currently logged in user's id, if its not in the database then there is something wrong when inserting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219973/discussion-between-jyo-and-peter-haddad).

Comment: user.uid is fine it matched the document ID but cardColor is still showing as false.

Comment: @Jyo Did you check what I answered in chat?

Comment: Yes looking into it. As of now things are still the same, cardColor is still showing as false.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion? can you try and debug it, add breakpoint to check if it is entering setState before the build method
If it is not entering it before the build, then try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901002/is-there-a-way-to-load-async-data-on-initstate-method/51901311#51901311
if the above also didnt work then you have to do another FutureBuilder @Jyo

Comment: After struggling for hours and with all your help @Peter Issue is fixed. I usedWidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // executes after build
}). Which at first did not give any solution but now its working all fine. I appreciate all your help. Thank you again.