# Why there is no list records returning in this flutter code application?

Tags: flutter

I'm receiving the following error while trying to display a user's all appointments with their corresponding date and title from databse. Can anyone please point out how to fix it?(Solved!)

Issue: Why there is no list records returning in this flutter code application?

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend/main.dart';
import 'package:frontend/util/authentication.dart';
import 'package:frontend/util/serverDetails.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:frontend/components/appointment.dart';
import 'package:frontend/screens/appointmentdetail.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:frontend/screens/appointments.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class AppointmentList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppointmentListState createState() => _AppointmentListState();
}

class _AppointmentListState extends State<AppointmentList>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = Map<DateTime, List>();
    getAppointments();
  }

  getAppointments() async {
    String currentToken = await Authentication.getCurrentToken();
    print(currentToken);
    if (currentToken == null) {
      print('bouncing');
      Authentication.bounceUser(context);
    } else {
      String auth = "Bearer " + currentToken;
      String url = ServerDetails.ip +
          ':' +
          ServerDetails.port +
          ServerDetails.api +
          'me/appointments';
      print(url);
      Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": auth};
      print(headers);
      var jsonResponse = null;
      var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("200" + response.body);
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
          setState(() {
            for (var doc in jsonResponse) {
              Appointment temp = Appointment.fromJson(doc);
              print("TEMP" + temp.date.toString());
              //print("TEMP" + temp.duration.toString());
              if (_events[temp.date] == null) {
                print("deb1" + temp.date.toString());
                _events[temp.date] = List()..add(temp);
              } else {
                //_events[temp.date] = List()..add(temp);
                _events[temp.date].add(temp);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body);
      }
    }
  }

  void _allDataSelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('CALLBACK: _allDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
                }),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Appointment", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            brightness: Brightness.light,
//          backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
            elevation: 0.5,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                color: Colors.black,
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_day),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Appointments()));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
            children: _selectedEvents
                .map((event) => Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                    child: (event is Appointment)
                        ? ListTile(
                            leading: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              //Show Weekday, Month and day of Appiontment
                              Text(
                                  DateFormat('EE').format(event.date) +
                                      '  ' +
                                      DateFormat.MMMd().format(event.date),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                              //Show Start Time of Appointment
                              Text(DateFormat.jm().format(event.date),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    height: 1.5,
                                  )),
                              //Show End Time of Appointment
                              Text(
                                DateFormat.jm().format(event.date.add(
                                    Duration(minutes: event.duration ?? 0))),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                              ),
                            ]), //Text(DateFormat.Hm().format(event.date)),//DateFormat.Hm().format(now)
                            title: Text(event.title),
                            trailing: event.status == 'UNCONFIRMED'
                                ? Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    //event.status=='CONFIRMED' ?
                                    Icon(Icons.error,
                                        color: Colors.pink,
                                        //size:25.0,
                                        semanticLabel:
                                            'Unconfirmed Appointment'), //:Container(width:0,height:0),
                                    Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                                  ])
                                : Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {});
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          AppointmentDetail(event)));
                            },
                          )
                        : null))
                .toList()));
  }
}
```

Another part of code for appointment.dart, which shows how that appointment looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Appointment {
  final String id;
  final String pid;
  final String title;
  final String detail;
  final DateTime date;
  final int duration;
  final String note;
  final String userNote;
  final String status;

  var doctor;

  Appointment(
      {this.id,
      this.pid,
      this.title,
      this.detail,
      this.date,
      this.duration,
      this.note,
      this.userNote,
      this.status});

  factory Appointment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Appointment(
        id: json['id'],
        pid: json['uid'],
        title: json['title'],
        detail: json['detail'],
        date: DateTime.parse(json['date']),
        duration: json['duration'] as int,
        note: json['note'],
        userNote: json['user_note'],
        status: json['status']);
  }
}
```

Here is the expected outcomes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CLbi.jpg)

Here is the new outcomes: (should have the expected outcomes below the 'Appointment'title)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcYHy.jpg)

Here is the update code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = Map<DateTime, List>();
    getAppointments().then((result) {
      print("result:$result");
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Here is the console output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7MjK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `_selectedEvents` is null, it is not initialized. Code which uses the `_selectedEvents` variable is `_allDataSelected()` method which isn't called.

It's a good practice to initialize the variables like this:

```dart
List _selectedEvents = [];
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your help! It did solve the error! However, it only returns a page with a title and button without my expected lists of appointment. Images are updated again, please help!

Comment: Cool. I'm glad I could help. For the second issue, can you explain? May be edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: New images just added, why there is no list records returning?

Comment: `_selectedEvents` is empty. `_allDataSelected()` isn't call. Is it related to **expected lists of appointment**?

Comment: Yes, they are and how should I call them properly if I wish to return all appointment records in the list?

Comment: Instead of editing the question title, it's better to ask a new one.

Comment: Sure thing, I would mark you as solving the quesiton already. Can you give me any specific suggestions on calling that _allDataSelected to return all records?

Comment: One option would be to use FutueBuilder and another one is to call the setState. Let me update my answer with the 2nd approach as it'll require minimal refactor compare to 1st one. Try if it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647682/4593315 this answer would help for the 2nd issue.

Add `then` to `getAppointments` call or use whencomplete as suggested in the comment of that answer.

Comment: Tried your 2nd answer. Output is added in the question for your reference. (Although the console output is different, the outcome is still empty). Now trying whencomplete

Comment: Using whencomplete will report error:
type'(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '() =>dynamic' of 'action'