# when I print for debug it shows type-->Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, dsc, flutter-android

**simply my task is to give a shared data to the variable "type" , please help me out**

*this sample code is main.dart and i used shared preferences for data transfer and the key for type is "typeOfUser" , I saw so many blogs and even stackoverflow, Questions but none of them suited for me *

code follows :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nativestore/database/datatrans.dart';
import 'package:nativestore/homepage.dart';
import 'package:nativestore/loginout/loginpage.dart';
import 'package:nativestore/shophomepage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'loginout/auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: routePage(),
    );
  }
}

class routePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  routePageState createState() => routePageState();
}

class routePageState extends State<routePage> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  int type;
  bool isLoggedin = false;
  getIntValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int val = prefs.getInt('typeOfUser');
    return val;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("type-->${getIntValuesSF()}");
    print("Init state");
    _auth.autoLogin().then((value) {
      if (value == 'null') {
        print(isLoggedin);
        setState(() {
          isLoggedin = false;
        });
      } else if (value != null) {
        setState(() {
          isLoggedin = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoggedin = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  // var Utype = GetUserType(type:"ko")
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoggedin == true
        ? (type == 2)
            ? homePage()
            : ShopHomePage()
        : loginPage();
  }
}
```

output :

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Redmi Note 8...
Restarted application in 2,645ms.
I/flutter (14262): type-->Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (14262): Init state
```

so please help me.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You have marked `getIntValuesSF` as `async` which means it must return a `Future`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to load async data on InitState method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901002/is-there-a-way-to-load-async-data-on-initstate-method)

Comment: yeah , but idk how to print that `getIntValuesSf` , can you please help with code. and my main intention is to store the shared data in `int type`. so if your answer is to store means it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your code prints `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` is because the instance of `getIntValuesSF()` is being printed and not the value it returns. What you can do here is to run the async function and using `then` to fetch its return value when the future completes.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIntValuesSF().then((value) {
        debugPrint('type-->$value');
        // do functions requiring value parameter
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works, I totally forgot to use `then` thanks

Answer (score 0):

change it:

```
print("type-->${getIntValuesSF()}");
```

to:

```
var value = await getIntValuesSF();
print("type-->${value.toString()}");
```

Comment: oops :( still the issue is same .

Comment: it shows like this . [link](https://ibb.co/yBQptGD)

Comment: bro add the void initState() async {}