# Async await does not wait for the output to return

Tags: android, flutter, asynchronous, mobile, async-await

I am making an bungalow reservation system with spring rest back end and flutter front end.
In this I want to get a list of bungalows.
So I decided to make a method to get the list of bungalows in a method using HttpService class that I made to handle the rest end points, That method is getBungalows() method.
Then I called this method by overriding initstate().
But the problem is that before my initstate() is completed. my build method starts.
To prove this I printed two lines 'print' and 'print build' as I thought I get 'print build' first. what am I doing wrong here. Please help.

**Method to retrieve data from rest back end**

When this happened I first checked this method but this works fine and return the desired result.

```
Future<List<Bungalow>> getBungalows() async {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse('$url/bungalows/');
  http.Response response = await http.get(uri);

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   List<Bungalow> bungalows = List<Bungalow>.from(
      json.decode(response.body).map((x) => Bungalow.fromJson(x)));
   // print(bungalows.first.address + 'asafafasfafdfgfgarfgargafvfrvaerg');
   return bungalows;
 } else {
   throw 'Unable to retrieve data';
 }
 }
```

**Code of the HomeScreen**

```
 class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   HttpService httpService = HttpService();
   late List<Bungalow> bungalows;
   bool isLoggedIn = false;
   User? user;

   void getBungalows() async {
     bungalows = await httpService.getBungalows();
     print('done');
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (widget.user != null) {
   isLoggedIn = true;
   user = widget.user;
   }
   print('done build');
   return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: Column(
    children: [
      Text(isLoggedIn ? user!.userDetail.username : 'No login'),
      // TextButton(
      //     onPressed: () {
      //       setState(() {
      //         getBungalows();
      //         print(bungalows.first.address);
      //       });
      //     },
      //     child: Text('click'))
     ],
  ),
);
}

@override
 void initState() {
   getBungalows();
   
 }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
I/flutter (22248): done build
I/flutter (22248): done
```

Comment: you do not await in initState so what you expected?

Comment: the result is what I'd expect from what the code is right now.

Comment: i have done the await in getBungalow() method.

Comment: setState with bungalows after you get it

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla what do i have to do to get the done printed first and then done build.

Comment: @Selvin where should i put setState

Comment: @Selvin I initially tried putting set state in initState but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is behaving correctly, initState function is not async and method getBungalows() is called in parallel.
You should either use setState in getBungalows, or add a listener, or use the `then` keyword, or use StreamBuilder.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647682/305135

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: `void getBungalows() async {
    var list = await httpService.getBungalows();
    setState(() {
      bungalows = list;
    });
  }`

Comment: i tried the above method and this gives the same output

Comment: Create a DartPad and share, maybe I can help.