# SharedPreferences data does not have time to be displayed in the widget

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I created a model class for Provider. Which will fit the function of getting data from SharedPreferences

```
Future getDataPerson() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
id = prefs.getInt('id') ?? 000;
name = prefs.getString('name') ?? "Фамилия Имя Отчество";
phone = prefs.getString('phone') ?? "3231313";
email = prefs.getString('email') ?? "";
accessToken =  prefs.getString('accessToken') ?? "нет токенааа";
_login = prefs.getString('login') ?? "нет логинааа";
_password = prefs.getString('password') ?? "нет пароляяя";
notifyListeners();
}
```

That's how I implement my Provider

```
body: MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ApiClient>(create: (_)=>ApiClient()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<FinalModel>(create: (_)=>FinalModel()),
    ],
    child: FinalScreenState(),
  ),
```

In initState, I call this function.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  finalModel = Provider.of<FinalModel>(context,listen: false);
  getDataPerson();
  }
  Future getDataPerson() async{
return await finalModel.getDataPerson();
 }
```

And in the code I get these variables and paste them into Text

```
idController.text = finalModel.getId.toString();
return Padding(padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 10,right: 1,left: 1),
    child:Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: idController,
       ))
);
```

However, only the values that I wrote in the code are inserted into the text. In this line it is "3231313"

```
prefs.getString('phone') ?? "3231313";
```

I tried calling the get Data Person function in different places in the code. In the build method itself.

The data I want to insert I take from json immediately after the user logs in using the button and receives a response from the api

```
var statusOne =await apiClient.signIn(_loginEmail1.text, _passwordParol1.text);
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
bool status = map['status'];
if (status == true) {
  //Entry in SharedPreferences
  setDataPerson();
  //The screen on which the data is displayed
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'final');}
```

method setDataPerson()

```
  void setDataPerson() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var statusOne =
    await apiClient.signIn(_loginEmail1.text, _passwordParol1.text);
var rawJson = AuthModel.fromJson(statusOne.data);
await prefs.setInt('id', rawJson.data!.performerId!);
await prefs.setString('name', rawJson.data!.fullName!);
await prefs.setString('phone', rawJson.data!.phone!);
await prefs.setString('accessToken', rawJson.data!.accessToken!);
}
```

Build method

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          IdWidget(),
          NameWidget(),
          PhoneWidget(),
          EmailWidget(),
        ],
      );
 }
```

PhoneWidget

```
class PhoneWidget extends StatelessWidget {  
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var finalModel = Provider.of<FinalModel>(context,listen: true);
return Padding(padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10,right: 
   1,left: 1),
    child: Consumer<FinalModel>(
    builder: (context, model, widget) {
      finalModel.phoneController.text = model.phone;
      return Center(
      child: TextField(
        controller: finalModel.phoneController,
        enabled: false,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Телефон",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ));
    })
   );
  }
  }
```

However, even if you do not receive this data from the network and just write a regular string, the data will not have time to be displayed on the screen.

It's worth noting here that when I restart the screen. And that is, I update the initState and build method. Then the data is updated and immediately displayed on the screen
I am not considering inserting the listen:true parameter into provider, , because the getData Person function will be called too often.

Comment: please show us your `setDataPerson` method.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901002/is-there-a-way-to-load-async-data-on-initstate-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `Consumer` widget to your `Column`widget so registered listeners will be called.

```
   Widget IdWidget() {
    return Consumer<YourModelClass>(
        builder: (context, model, widget) => Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 10, right: 1, left: 1),
            child: Center(
                child: TextField(
              controller: model.id,
            ))));
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: print out `rawJson.data!.phone!`. What value you get?

Comment: I get the right answer. and I have everything displayed when the page is refreshed

Comment: Show us your `build` method.

Comment: However, the setData Person method is executed before get Data Person. But why is the getData Person method not updated

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //finalModel.getDataPerson();
    print('от профиль ${finalModel.getPhone}');
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          IdWidget(),
          NameWidget(),
          PhoneWidget(),
          EmailWidget(),
        ],
      );
  }

Comment: This works if you embed final Model.get Data Person(); inside builder: Consumer. However, it also works like listen:true. That is, it calls this function too often.

Comment: don't put `final Model.get Data Person();` inside builder. Put it in `initState`.

Comment: Then wrap all your `Column` Widget with `Consumer`.

Comment: I wrapped both the Id Widget() and Column() widget separately. If I wrap in Column() then I do not know how to pass the model parameter to Id Widget(). And when I wrap the Widget() Id separately, and pass the model parameter to the text, it doesn't work

Comment: Please update your post with your latest code.

Comment: Made an update.

Comment: add  `await` in front of `setDataPerson();`