# Provider/ChangeNotifier: Set state after Widget is build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

Im using the Provider/ChangenNotifier Pattern to handle state as described [in the official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

I have a state field which I want to set after a Widget is build. However if I try to set in in the build method. I get an Error:

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Where can I call something like:

```
var state = Provider.of<StateModel>(context);
state.field = 'new Val';
```

Comment: Call it at child build.

Comment: Could you provide an example for this?

Comment: Can show the full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set the state during a build, if you want to test a change of state, put this code `state.field = 'new Val';` inside a button event, like `FloatActionButton` or a event after build completed (with Future.delayed or add post fram callback, see [Is there any callback to tell me when "build" function is done in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216448/is-there-any-callback-to-tell-me-when-build-function-is-done-in-flutter))

**Warning** If you are invoking `notifyListeners()` inside your state.field set, and listening changes in your widget with provider, It would cause an infinite cycle of rebuild... this is another reason that you can not set state during build...