# Setting provider state in InitState gives error

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I set a provider in the `initState` method? Tried doing `listen: false` but got an error:

```dart
final MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false);
if (myProvider.someVar == null) {
    myProvider.setSomeVar('yo');
}
```

I get the following error:

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Here's the providers method

```
void setSomeVar(String text) {
    someVar = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: In your Provider, setSomeVar() is calling notifyListeners().  This is a no-no in initState an build().  Try using a addPostFrameCallback to setSomeVar() after the build is complete.

Comment: @JonnyH but i set listen: false

Comment: Can you show your code for setSomeVar()?

Comment: What kind of Provider are you using? Can you show  the code

Comment: @JonnyH updated

Comment: @lenz Updated code

Comment: Review this question and see if it applys to your code as well...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584334/understand-how-listen-false-works-when-used-with-providersometype-ofcontext

Comment: Ah. Are you calling provider.of() “outside” of your build method?

Comment: @lenz Yes, but using listen false. It's in initState

Comment: ... if so, remember that provider needs the build context

Comment: M ore information here..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250572/provider-changenotifier-set-state-after-widget-is-build?rq=1

Comment: To the best of my understanding, listen false setting prevents rebuilds when the value changes. But your provider still needs the build context

Comment: @lenz So would it make sense to call the provider in the build method? `Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false)`

Comment: Yes 100%. This would update the value but without forcing a rebuild of the widget’s UI

Comment: There is a workaround, but it’s a bit complex, it’s probably way easier just to review the logic in your code and use provider in the build method. But for reference it involves extracting context outside of the build method.

Comment: @lenz Still gettting the error

Comment: You’re getting the same error wih the provider inside of your build method?

Comment: @lenz yups same error

Comment: addPostFramCallback

Comment: @JonnyH That works! thanks! Can I do this in initState?

Comment: yes you can.  context is available there.

Comment: @JonnyH Can u post as answer so that I can accept please

Comment: Done.  Also added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Provider, setSomeVar() is calling notifyListeners(). This is a no-no in initState and build(). Try using a addPostFrameCallback to setSomeVar() after the build is complete.

Also, when using addPostFrameCallback, for something that uses context, you should check for context == null as a precaution.

```
initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (context == null) return;
    log('Navigating to SplashPage');
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, splashRoute);
  });
  
  super.initState();
}
```