# setState in futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I want to use `setState` in `FutureBuilder`, but keeps getting

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I have declared ratio as global variables. I would like to update the value of ratio. The ration can be only calculated once image's width and height is successfully get.

```
 Widget _showItem() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _bloc.selectImage(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
              break;

            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Image image = new Image.network(snapshot.data);
                Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
                image.image.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
                    new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool _) {
                  completer.complete(image.image);

                  setState(() {
                num maxHeightRatio = 300 / image.image.height;
                num maxWidthRatio = 400 / image.image.width;
                    this.ratio = maxWidthRatio.coerceAtMost(maxHeightRatio);
                  });
                }));

                return CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: snapshot.data.toString(),
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: imageProvider
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                );
              } else {
                return Image.asset('assets/no_image.png');
              }
              break;

            default:
              return Text("Error");
          }
        });
  }
```

I understand we should not using `setState` in `FutureBuilder`, but what is the solution for this since I need to update the global variable?

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/6891637)

Comment: @AjilO. my widget will keep building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to move your future call to the `initState` method since you don't want to call your `selectImage` every time your widget gets built. Once you move the call outside your build method you can do all your calculations and then `setState`.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  setup();
}

setup() async {
  var data = await _bloc.selectImage();
  // do calculations using data
  // setState
}
```

Read more on this [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#why-is-fetchalbum-called-in-initstate).

Comment: selectImage is called on null

Comment: Make sure you’re initializing _bloc before you call selectImage