# Need a workaround for Indexedstack always being as big as the largest child

Tags: flutter

I have an indexed stack. First child widget has half the content that the second child widget has, but the first child widget's height is the same as the second child widget. This seems to be the expected result due to the design but its annoying because when I scroll on the first child widget, there is a bunch of extra space at the bottom. How can I work around this?

Why did the Flutter team even design it like this? Why not give the widget children the height according the the widgets, not according to whatever the largest child is?

Answer (score 10):

This solution preserves state, one of the key features of IndexedStack. Most of the posted solutions drop state on index change, and I needed to preserve state.

The Widget height has no restriction if active, and is constrained to a 1 pixel SizedBox if inactive. This makes the active Widget largest, so your Widget is rendered at it's personal size without added space.

```
IndexedStack(
  index: selectedIndex,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
        height: selectedIndex == 0 ? null : 1,
        child: Widget1()),
    SizedBox(
        height: selectedIndex == 1 ? null : 1,
        child: Widget2()),
    SizedBox(
        height: selectedIndex == 2 ? null : 1,
        child: Widget3())
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use visibility inside a IndexedStack. Like this:

```
IndexedStack(
  index: selectedIndex,
  children: [
    Visibility(
     visible: selectedIndex == 0,
     child: Container(
       height: 300,
     ),
    Visibility(
      visible: selectedIndex == 1,
      child: Container(
      height: 100,
    )
  ]
)
```

you can do this inside a column too just replace indexedstack with column.

Comment: This works very well if you don't need to preserve state of the child widgets. If you need the state preservation feature of IndexedStack, choose another option.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue today.
My workaround is to only render the Stack which is visible based on the index number.

```
      Widget _buildPage2() {
        if(index != 1) { // Empty container
          return Container();
        }
        return Column( // Actual Widget which has a different height
          children: <Widget>[]
        );
     }
```

I still have not figured out how to get `controller.animateTo` working.

**Edit**

I got `controller.animateTo` to work by triggering a `Future.delayed` event.
As a better approach you could use `WidgetBindings`, as explained in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/4746528).

Comment: Thanks! This finally helped me with my approach

Answer (score 1):

`IndexedStack` use `Visibility.maintain`, so if you want just not keep the largest space in all Widget, you can simple use Stack in this way.

```
final List<Widget> widgets;
final int currentIndex;

Stack(  
 children: List<Widget>.generate(widgets.length, (index) {
    return Visibility(
        visible: currentIndex==index,
        maintainState: true, // add this to mantain state
        maintainSize: false, // this should be false or null
        child: widgets[index]
    );

 }),
)
```

Using `Offstage` instead of `Visibility` may also be a good solution

Comment: It works great! By the way `maintainSize` is `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found this workaround.

```
class CustomIndexedStack extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomIndexedStack(
      {super.key, required this.index, required this.children});

  final List<Widget> children;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: children
          .mapIndexed(
              (widget, i) => Offstage(offstage: index != i, child: widget))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

extension IndexedIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<T> mapIndexed<T>(T Function(E e, int i) f) {
    var i = 0;
    return map((e) => f(e, i++));
  }
}
```

Comment: please add some comment for code explanation