# Flutter GetX Unable to show Snackbar after Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-getx

I was trying to show a Snackbar after navigating to a new page with the Get Package.
I passed the "snackbar-ingredients" as a parameter to the new widget and wanted to show it then.
I got an error that indicates that the built of the widget didn't finish before I tried to show the snackbar. That obviously didn't work. I get why.. but I don't have a fitting solution.

Is there a way to wait for the build to finish before calling the snackbar?

Thanks for your help!

(PS: in another post someone said to refer to the scaffoldKey.. I am not sure how to do that in Get.snackbar())

Comment: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2),()=> Get.snackbar()).whenComplete(()=> Get.toNamed());. Try this if this helps.

Comment: Take a look at `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/2301224.  This will run code you supply (such as showing a snackbar) after the widget build is complete.

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback
That's the one! 
You are a livesaver! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Arbiter Chill answer works for me. I tried this:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), ()=>Get.snackbar("Error", response.body,
        backgroundColor: AppColor.blueBackgroundColor, colorText: AppColor.white));
```