# Is there an function for "wait frame to end" like "WaitForEndOfFrame" in unity?

Tags: flutter, flame

I need to do some calculations between every `update()`, so I need to ensure that a function is processed before the next frame.

Is there any way to achieve this? Just like "WaitForEndOfFrame" in Unity?

Comment: @pskinkthis this is about the update-loop in  Flame, a `Ticker` would not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `updateTree` in your `FlameGame` (or in your `Component`, if you only want it to happen before the `update`s of a subtree) and do your calculations right before all the other components start updating. This would be right after the last frame, except for the first frame, but that one you can skip by setting a boolean.

So something like this:

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  bool isFirstTick = true;

  @override
  void updateTree(double dt) {
    if(!isFirstTick) {
      // Do your calculations
    } else {
      isFirstTick = false;
    }
    super.updateTree(dt);
  }
}
```

But I have to ask, why do you need to do this? `render` won't be called until all the `update` calls are done, do can't you just put your calculations in the normal `update` method?

Answer (score -1):

In Flutter we don't get an `update()` function unlike Unity. That is in the default API that we use, there are ways to tap into something of that effect. Normally we use a `Ticker` and create an animation to get periodic updates synced with screen refresh rate.

However, if what you are trying to do is to run something in between `build()` calls, `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback()` may be what you are looking for.

Here is a detailed answer that may help in this regard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/679553

Comment: This question is about Flame, which does have an `update` method.

Comment: aha, ok I missed that in the tags, thank you :D